# how to make different grounding

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, ground, grounding

yesterday when i ask about driving circuit, someone told me that it is a little use in optocoupler when i use the same ground everywhere. because so far (iam a green hand in electronic) i just connect the ground to the netral phase, i don't know how to create or connect the ground properly, so how to create a grounding, or how to connect it wisely?
from this picture also it has some grounding but not connected one another[image]

Comment: your schematic has no optocoupler, so there is no "separate ground" possible

Comment: For DC circuits, ground is 0V. But for AC circuits, neutral is 0V and ground is a separate connection entirely used for safety purposes that is not supposed to carry current unless something goes wrong. What are you talking about exactly?

Comment: one optocoupler that you are familiar with, and that you probably use a lot, is the remote control for your TV ...... i am pretty sure that the grounds of the remote control and of the TV are not connected together

Comment: An optocoupler has two purpose: (1) it is an isolation barrier between it's input and output side. If you connect a pin on both sides of the optocoupler to ground it is like you are cutting a hole in that barrier. (2) The voltages on the output do not have to be relative/referenced to the voltages on the input at all. Connecting ground on both sides means you are defeating this purpose too by sidestepping it. You might as well not have it. It is like getting an airplane so you can ignore what is on the ground when travelling, but then driving it along the ground anyways instead of flying.

Comment: The circuit you posted does not have an optocoupler. It is using something fancy, but cheaper than an optocoupler. It is called a bootstrap capacitor (C1. C2) and bootstrap diode (D1). Q2's gate can be driven directly with the +12V supply since it's source pin sits at ground and the +12V supply is referenced to ground (0V).

Comment: [cont...] But Q1's source pin sits at the voltage of OUT, and this changes all the time as the load runs but you need 12V between Q1 gate and source pin (OUT) to turn it on. Imagine if you took a capacitor and connected it across 12V and ground of the power supply and let it charge up and then removed it. Now you have 12V sitting in a capacitor. Then put the capacitor back into the circuit with the negative pin connected to Q1's source pin (OUT). Now you have 12V relative to Q1's source pin. No matter what Q1 source pin voltage is, you always have 12V higher to drive the gate.

Comment: [cont...] That's what bootstrapping is. You have that 12V floating on top of the voltage of the Q1 source pin as long as the capacitor is charged. Since it discharges you periodically have to take it off and put it back between the +12V and GND(0V) of the power supply to recharge it before putting it back on Q1. An optocoupler is much more straightforward (but more expensive).

Comment: okay, thank u very much for the explnanation, i get it, and how to make an independent grounding in pcb? what thing i have to make it from?

Comment: Explain what you mean by independent grounding. What parts of the circuit do you want to each have their own ground?

Comment: i mean howt to make a different grounding usually when i want to maek ground lane only connect the ground line to the negative side of the battery or supply, but i don't know how (for the example) the remote tv make its ground path? do it connect the ground to the negative battery side too or how?

Comment: @rahul, why are you thinking that a remote control has a ground path to the TV? .... why would it need to have one? .....  the only link between the two is a beam of light  ......... please post a schematic of the optocoupler circuit that you mentioned in your post

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the simplest opto-couplers that I can think of.

It would be simpler if the flashlight was replaced by the sun.

The receiver indicates the relative brightness of light hitting the sensor.

As light brightness changes, the amount of current flowing in the circuit changes.

Do you see any reason why the two circuits require a common ground to operate correctly?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuAGWr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now add some dangerous voltage to the circuit, either by accident or by design.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIbDrp.png)</sup>

Now add a common ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgnXsB.png)</sup>